# .is(':checked') not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hello friends I want when user checked the radio box then the text will show following is my code you can also check my code here http://jsfiddle.net/mY4N5/

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
  <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" id="red"/>
  </label>
</form>
<div id="dis">
hi

</div>
```

Script

```
$('#dis').css('display','none');

    if($('#red').is(':checked'))
    {
    $('#dis').css('display','block');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#dis').css('display','none');
    };
```

Comment: If you want it just initialize when the page loads, put it in the `ready` function.  If you want it to update based on an active change, tie the logic to the change event: http://jsfiddle.net/mY4N5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use radiobutton and the value of specific radio is important you can use this
http://jsfiddle.net/LcEn6/
If you want just have one of them checked and no mater what which one you can use this.
http://jsfiddle.net/V4W7j/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#dis').css('display','none');
        $('#red').click(function(){
           if($('#red').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#dis').css('display','block');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dis').css('display','none');
            };
        });
    }) ;
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click or change event to run the condition

```
$('#dis').css('display','none');

$('#red').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#dis').css('display','block');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#dis').css('display','none');
    };
});
```